# How should my class look to serialize XML?

Tags: c#, xml

This is how my class is

```
class SerClass
{
    Line[] Line;
    Circle[] Circle;
    Square[] Square;
}
```

And this is how my XML is coming out:

```
<Line .../>
<Line .../>
<Circle .../>
<Circle .../>
<Square .../>
<Square .../>
```

What should my code look like for me to be able to specify the order of the elements, say:

```
<Square .../>
<Line .../>
<Circle .../>
<Line .../>
<Circle .../>
<Square .../>
```

Comment: Any explanation on WHY you want such a random order of elements? The output looks appropriate from the way your class looks. It has 3 arrays, and it lists each element in each array in order then lists each element in the next array etc..

Comment: I think the only way to accomplish this would be to override / implement your own serialization function.

Comment: we can not set different order for each item in same list.We can set Order property for each property like [XmlElement(ElementName = "Lines", Order = 1)]

Comment: It seems by your XML that each group of three items (an square, a line and a circle) conform one "object", so, why not instead of three arrays of lines/squares/circles you don't use an array of a new class type with those three elements?

Comment: ZACH: I am trying to serialize geometry into an XML. I am using an algorithm that parses through a graph and lists the items in an order.

Comment: FVU: Made a minor change to the code in the question. Serializing the above class will automatically create the first XML.

Comment: GUSMAN: The order of elements is completely arbitrary. But, what you said is something I need to consider.

Comment: What are you using to serialize that class SerClass? I don't think it is `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` because it wouldn't serialize the private arrays you have there. I agree with Gusman though, if you need to see a set of a square, circle and line together, it should be its own object.

Comment: ZACK: Yes. The class I have here is not the code I have. It is just a simple representation.

Comment: ZACK: If I do go with the new object; I will need to have an array of this new object. When I serialize it, I will see the new-object-array name in the XML. Right?

Comment: PRESCOTT: Is there a way to override just the serialization function of one class? In this case the SerClass. In my XML, the SerClass is just one XMLElement within a very large class structure.

Comment: @GuccesInu Please learn how comment replies work: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: @GuccesInu, yes you will see the new-object-array name in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what were talking about. I added a new class called GeometryCollection that has a single Line, Square and Circle object, then in the SerClass you have an array of GeometryCollection objects called GeoCollection, that when serialized produces the output below where the Circle, Square and Line are grouped within the GeometryCollection element.

Let me know if something like this suits your needs, or if there is anything wrong with it that you may not be able to use and I can try to advise on what to do, but as far as I know, this would be the best way to group the Line, Square and Circle objects together, if that's what you are going for.

## Command line program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace CommandLineProgram.Miscellaneous
{
    public class SerializeSerClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerClass));
            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                ser.Serialize(writer, new SerClass());
                Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Line
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Line()
        {
            Name = "Line";
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class Circle
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Circle()
        {
            Name = "Circle";
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class Square
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Square()
        {
            Name = "Square";
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class SerClass
    {
        public GeometryCollection[] GeoCollection { get; set; }
        public SerClass()
        {
            GeoCollection = new GeometryCollection[] 
            { 
                new GeometryCollection() 
                { 
                    Circle = new Circle(), 
                    Square = new Square(), 
                    Line = new Line() 
                },
                new GeometryCollection() 
                { 
                    Circle = new Circle(), 
                    Square = new Square(), 
                    Line = new Line() 
                },
                new GeometryCollection() 
                { 
                    Circle = new Circle(), 
                    Square = new Square(), 
                    Line = new Line() 
                } 
            };
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class GeometryCollection
    {
        public Line Line { get; set; }
        public Square Square { get; set; }
        public Circle Circle { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Produces XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SerClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <GeoCollection>
    <GeometryCollection>
      <Line>
        <Name>Line</Name>
      </Line>
      <Square>
        <Name>Square</Name>
      </Square>
      <Circle>
        <Name>Circle</Name>
      </Circle>
    </GeometryCollection>
    <GeometryCollection>
      <Line>
        <Name>Line</Name>
      </Line>
      <Square>
        <Name>Square</Name>
      </Square>
      <Circle>
        <Name>Circle</Name>
      </Circle>
    </GeometryCollection>
    <GeometryCollection>
      <Line>
        <Name>Line</Name>
      </Line>
      <Square>
        <Name>Square</Name>
      </Square>
      <Circle>
        <Name>Circle</Name>
      </Circle>
    </GeometryCollection>
  </GeoCollection>
</SerClass>
```